# How to list files(with spaces) in s3 bucket using shell script (bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am listing all the files in s3 bucket and writing it in a text file. For example, my bucket has the following list of files:

```
text.zip
fixed.zip
hello.zip
good test.zip
```

I use the following code:

```
fileList=$(aws s3 ls s3://$inputBucketName/ | awk '{print $4}')
if [ ! -z "$fileList" ]
then
    $AWS_CLI s3 ls s3://$inputBucketName/ | awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' > s3op.txt
    sort -k1,1 -k2 s3op.txt > s3op_srt.txt
    awk '{print $3}' s3op_srt.txt > filesOrder.txt
fi
cat filesOrder.txt;
```

After this when I iterate the files from the file I created (I will delete the files in S3 at the end of the loop, so the file won't be processed again):

```
fileName=`head -1 filesOrder.txt`
```

the files are listed like below:

```
text.zip
fixed.zip
hello.zip
good
```

So the problem is that, the list is not able to list the files with spaces correctly.

As the file name is returned as "good" and not as "good test.zip", it is not able to delete the file from S3.

Expected Result is

```
text.zip
fixed.zip
hello.zip
good test.zip
```

I used following command to delete files in S3:

```
aws s3 rm s3://$inputBucketName/$fileName
```

Comment: Always put variables holding filenames inside double quotes.

Comment: Your `awk` is using a 'space' as a separator. A simple solution would be to just include 1 more column in `awk`. So just print $4 and $5 instead of just $4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LohitGupta

Your case doesn't work, when there is more than one space. So i tried the below one.

awk '{ print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }'

Answer (score 0):

Put the full file path under double quotes.
For example:

```
aws s3 rm "s3://test-bucket/good test.zip"
```

In your case, it would be:

```
aws s3 rm "s3://$inputBucketName/$fileName"
```

Here even if the fileName has spaces, it'll be deleted.